# Conditional Logic for Gridview ItemTemplate (using mark up only)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview as shown below. When the EmpType is contract the EmpID must be masked as "XXX";  for regular employees, actual EmpID should be shown. Also, when it is masked, I need to add a **button control** in the EmpID column.

I need to do it using **mark-up**; not using code behind. How can we write the conditional logic for Gridview's ItemTemplate for this logic?

Note: .Net 4.0

```
    <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AssociateID" DataField="AssociateID" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmpID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("EmpID")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmpType" DataField="EmpType" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
    List<Associate> associatesList = new List<Associate>();
    associatesList.Add(new Associate { AssociateID = 1, EmpID = 101, EmpType = "Contract" });
    associatesList.Add(new Associate { AssociateID = 2, EmpID = 102, EmpType = "Regular" });
    Gridview1.DataSource = associatesList;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following works

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmpID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("EmpType")) == "Contract" ? "XXX" : Convert.ToString(Eval("EmpID"))%>

                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
                    Visible='<%# Eval("EmpType") == "Contract" ? true : false %>' />

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Related:**

Row number can be obtained by following [Get GridView Selected Row Values using Page Previous Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831647/get-gridview-selected-row-values-using-page-previous-page)

```
CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
<%# Eval("EmpType") == "Contract" ? "XXX" : Convert.ToString(Eval("EmpID"))%>
```

Instead of

```
 <%# Eval("EmpID")%>
```

Comment: You got warning for above code. I tested that didn't get any warning

Comment: Edited. Glad you overcame warning, I think there is no need to convert EmpType to string as it is already a string and coming to your question you can control the visibility of control from code behind.

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous. If we aren't supposed to use globals, and ItemTemplate's are completely useless outside of producing static stagnant content, then why the heck am I even using ASP.
I've begun using the Request storage to store datasets, and looping them in normal <% %> blocks, so that I can actually do something useful with my page. How is it that this same issue has existed for 9 years, and they have yet to produce ANY improvement whatsoever on the whole of ASP.