# Get GridView Selected Row Values using Page Previous Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridView in ConsumerList page. When Edit button is clicked (in each row), it is navigated to a EditConsumer page. In the EditConsumer page, I need to get the values of the selected row using **Page.PreviousPage**. How to get these values?

```
    public void Consumer_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "CustomEdit")
        {
            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            string consumerID = grdConsumers.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
            string consumerName = grdConsumers.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
            string consumerUrl = grdConsumers.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Text;
            string consumerStatus = grdConsumers.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].Text;

            Response.Redirect("EditConsumer.aspx?RowIndex=" + rowIndex);
        }
    }
```

MARKUP

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdConsumers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="resultGridTable"
                GridLines="None" EnableViewState="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="Consumers_Sorting" OnRowCommand="Consumer_RowCommand">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                <Columns>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>

                             <asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" CssClass="actionButtonView"
                                  Text="VIEW" Style="width: 40px" BackColor="Orange"
                                  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 

                             <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="CustomEdit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"
                              CssClass="actionButtonEdit"
                                  Text="EDIT" Style="width: 35px" BackColor="Orange"
                                  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 

                             <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="actionButtonDelete"
                                  Text="DELETE" Style="width: 55px" BackColor="Orange"
                                  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

                             <asp:Button ID="btnPing" runat="server" CssClass="actionButtonPing"
                                  Text="PING" Style="width: 35px" BackColor="Orange"
                                  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

                         </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Consumer ID" DataField="ConsumerID" SortExpression="ConsumerID"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Consumer Name" DataField="ConsumerName" SortExpression="ConsumerName"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Consumer URL" DataField="ConsumerURL" SortExpression="ConsumerURL"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" SortExpression="Status"></asp:BoundField>



                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: `PreviousPage` is only `!= null` with [cross page posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx), [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirect.aspx) will not work. So you could for example use [`Server.Transfer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx).

You could provide a public property `SelectedConsumer` that returns a custom object of the curerently selected row in the `GridView`.

```
public Consumer SelectedConsumer
{
    get {
        if (grdConsumers.SelectedRow == null)
            return null;

        var c = new Consumer();
        c.consumerID = grdConsumers.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        c.consumerName = grdConsumers.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        c.consumerUrl = grdConsumers.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
        c.consumerStatus = grdConsumers.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;

        return c;
    }
}
```

Now you only have to cast the `PreviousPage` property to the correct page type:

```
var consumerList = (ConsumerList)Page.PreviousPage;
var selectedConsumer = consumerList.SelectedConsumer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [how to use Page.PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx).