# programmatically add an image to an array to add to grid view in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have an array of data that I am getting back from SQL and I want to add an image (Tick or Cross) to each row of the array depending on the result given. I was intending to do a foreach around the array and `if x==y` then display image a else display image b and then add this to the array before displaying the array in a gridview

```
c_gvResults.DataSource = arResults
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I can get an image from an images folder programmatically in c# asp.net and display this in the gridview based on the criteria above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really need to do is not to add the image to your array but add a URL to the array. Then you can use [ImageField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx) or use that URL as the source of an IMG tag in your gridview in a TemplateField. Some examples of how you do that is at [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/225414/Hyperlinked-Image-in-ASP-NET-GridView). If you don't know how to use TemplateFields, [check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx).

If you don't want to add a URL field to your data, to get the conditional formatting, your IMG tag can be as follows. The exact syntax might not be right but you get the point. :)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmpID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img src="<%# Eval("whatevercolumn") == "Correct" ? "tick.gif" : "cross.gif" %>"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Hi @Tombala

Thanks for your help this seems exactly what I am trying to achieve.  The problem I have is that I do not want to get the imageURLstring from the sql query where I am getting the other data from but add it an after.  I am currently at this stage but do not know how I can add the sTextString to my list to then pass to the gridview.

Comment: string sTextString = "";
               
                foreach (WebApplication.Data.Results.Result result in lResults))
                {
                    if (result.UserAnswer == result.CorrectAnswer)
                    {

                        sTextString = "..images/tick.png";

                    }
                    else
                    {                   
                        sTextString = "..images/cross.png";

                    } 
                }
                c_gvResults.DataSource = lResults.ToArray();
                c_gvResults.DataBind();

Comment: @user2192142 What you would do is use the IMG tag approach and check for the value in whatever column you want to check with an in-line if statement similar to what [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811023/conditional-logic-for-gridview-itemtemplate-using-mark-up-only) has. I updated the code with an example of this.

Comment: Hi @Tombala I have taken your advise and have this now working.  I was unable to use the eval as this only ever returned the cross.gif and not the tick.gif.
    <%--  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Status") == "Correct" ? "~/images/tick.png" : "~/images/cross.png" %>' />
</ItemTemplate>                                               
 </asp:TemplateField>--%>

Answer (score 1):

If within your query you are getting the file name of the JPG file you can probably add on the ASP page something like this under the `<Columns> </Columns>` tag of your GridView.

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="YourJPGFileNameColumn" 
               DataImageUrlFormatString="~\YourPathWhereTheImageIs\{0}.jpg" >
               <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
</asp:ImageField>
```

The "YourJPGFileNameColumn" has to be the column name return on your query and the {0} is where the value returned by your query is going to be.

For example if your query returns a table like this:

```
| ProductID |
 -----------
| 1234      |
| 010102    |
| 5678      |
```

You will write your code like this:

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ProductID" 
               DataImageUrlFormatString="~\YourPathWhereTheImageIs\{0}.jpg" >
               <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
</asp:ImageField>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get an `<img>` element in a column, not an actual image object. Specially since they are tick or cross. Just have the files somewhere, make the corresponding strings and then get those strings into the array.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to display the image in the Grid View but not write it back to the DB itself so you should look into handling the Grid View's RowDataBound event along with using row templates to add a custom column for display an image.

Test your expression in the event handler and then show the appropriate image in a custom column based on the outcome.